# mobile keyboard resize viewport

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

I'm doing a responsive web site and I have this problem. Everything works well until I select an [input type="text"] and comes out the keyboard, entire site is resized, it's like the screen size is only the part above the keyboard. I just want that mantain the normal size. I've tried all the solution proposed on stackoverflow an other forum too, bun nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

```
<head>
  <title>SchoolIn</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//other code
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm going to try to explain better.

I have a head section

```
//other code
<div class="head">
  //Here is some text 
</div>
//other code
```

Then a content section

```
//other code
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    //other code
    <input type="text" ...... />
    <input type="password" ..... />
    <input type="submit" ..... />
  </div>
</div>
//other code
```

All the element are in percentage there is nothin in pixels.

When the keyboad comes out the header, the container and the content div are redimensioned, instead the input fields and the button don't. In any case they came out from their container, becouse the container goes smaller and they maintain the original size. I don't know if I made my self clear.

The question is the same, how I make it to remain to the original size when the keyboard comes out?

Comment: How did you fix your issue? (I think I've tried all possible combination, includding yours, but no success. :( – Daniel Srp)

Comment: @Daniel Srp did you ever find out what was causing the issue? I'm having the exact same problem and can't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Try this piece of html. I'm using it for every of my pages and it always did what it should. Maybe yours isn't working because of the missing minimum-scale attribute.

Comment: I think I've tried all possible combination, includding yours, but no success. :(

Comment: Piece of line that saved my app.

Comment: Didn't make any difference to Chrome on android in 2019 - still resizes viewport

Answer (score 3):

No `<meta name='viewport'/>` or percentage fixes worked in my case (Android 2.3 browser), so I ended up with this CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

You also need to do this for anything with `height:auto`.

It's a hack, but it at least makes the website usable in this edge case. As soon as the user tries to zoom, it snaps out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've make it work, at least in part. The problem for me was that I made the HTML and BODY height 100%, so when the keyboard comes out the height becomes the part above it. If I don't declare any height it works just fine.

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

I said in part because I need the height of the device so I can make the proportion with the elements inside the page. If I don't declare the height the content of the page will be displayed in some smartphones for half screen, in other corectly. I've already made breaking points with media query, but I can't make it one for each resolution. I've create some ranges (ex: max-width:320 ---- min-width:321, max-width:480 .... and so one).

Again any ideas on how to solve the height problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

The size of any viewport based/percentage element will change when the virtual keyboard is invoked (Android). One fix is to get the size of the current inner window height (in px)
and then use that as the height of the element that you want to remain constant on keyboard popup.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* ... */
    var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('body').css({'height':windowHeight});
    /* ... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using viewport units for height of a division (div) .. I used pixels to define the height of the division.. now it's solved..

Answer (score 0):

Same as Shardul, my problem was a height fixed in VH unit instead of px. I forgot it as I did set it up months ago...

I finally used min-height 100vh to fix my footer height.

I just added a media query overwriting this rule when under 500px :

```
#root {
mix-height : 800px;
}
```

Comment: `mix-height` should be `min-height`